# What I think is sad / What I'm sad about

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one would you choose as commonly used one?

> 1. What I think is sad is some of my friends don't know what makes them happy.
> 2. What I'm sad about is some of my friends don't know what makes them happy.

Comment: This is going to be difficult to answer since the parts that are different convey a different meaning. Think about "I'm sad about something..." versus "Something that is sad".

Comment: When you use *What I think is sad* it is about your belief or opinion. When you use *What I'm sad about* is it is about something that makes you sad. The meanings are different so either could be OK.

Comment: I'll sometimes write this way, but will more often than not restructure the sentence so that I lose the "what" altogether: **"I'm sad because some of my friends don't know what makes them happy."** Using a _what_ like that isn't ungrammatical, but it can lead to awkward sentences – see how your first sentence uses the word "is" twice in just three words? (It's not wrong, but that doesn't mean it can't be improved.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I think is sad is some of my friends don't know what makes them
>   happy.
>   What I'm sad about is some of my friends don't know what makes
>   them happy.

This is the kind of colloquial statement (where "that" has been dropped from the complement clause) that requires the speaker to get the parsing rhythms and intonation patterns correct if the listener is going to follow along and understand.

In speech, there would be a pause after "What I think is sad" and also after "is", and a pause after "What I'm sad about" and again after "is".

What I think is sad
is
some of my friends don't know what makes them happy.

What I'm sad about
is
some of my friends don't know what makes them happy.

These pauses needn't be very long, but in conjunction with the intonation patterns they must clearly demarcate the clause boundaries.

The statements mean different things. In the first, the speaker is commenting on a state of affairs. In the second, the speaker is commenting on his own state of mind.